# Graphics card damage pin

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, shutdown, graphics, pin

I have RTX 2060 Graphics card. It randomly shutdown some times. When I removed it from motherboard then I realized that it has 2 half damage pin.

Damage pin close-up:
[image: Damage pin close-up]

I notice, my PC shutdown under extreme load. All the LEDs and fans were still working but according to display notification, it seems PC has been shutdown.

Should I be concerned about my Graphics card? Is it fatal? If no then what should I do to prolong my Graphics card life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get some soft acid like white vinegar a q-tip and a teeth brush. Give it a "gentle" rub and clean the copper oxidation.

Then clean everything with isopropyl alcohol(rubbing alcohol, best if 99.9% electronic grade)

Oxidation layers add resistance so they become hot stops, which are less conductive and could lead to electronic problems. Also those oxidation layers are conductive and can make a bridge. So when you have a high load things are going to go out of spec.

You need to research and understand which you have oxidation on those pins, Why did humidity make it there in the first place?

Comment: Are those fungus?

Comment: No, it's not fungi. Copper oxidation is green, something corrosive got on those pins, stayed there and oxidized them. Liquid made it there, maybe water cooling, a drink during installation or maybe a pet like a cat, marking their territory. It did happen to me with a CRT monitor back in '98, my housecat made the monitor his territory and when we turned it on it blew blue smoke. Not fun stuff.

Comment: Acid might be a bad idea - Contact cleaner is the 'right' choice  for this. Another thing I'd wonder is those contacts are usually plated to prevent this - so why did the plating get removed?

Comment: A mouse did live in there for few days maybe month before I blocked the large hole. I live in small town. I am not sure of I will ever find isopropyl alcohol and white vinegar a q-tip? Will it spread if I leave it untreated?

Comment: @MuhammadRokonuzzaman - Well it won’t work until you clean the card or replace the card. A mouse lived in your computer?